# How pass data in two Component using angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using EventEmitter with Services. Please help how I can pass data into second component on page redirect.

Comment: Your question is so unclear that noone can probably help you. Please see our [guide on how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [mcve]. To include it you can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service and Use Subject. Your service code look like this.

```
public data$ = new Subject<any>();
```

In your both component just subscribe to this subject.

```
this.dataService.data$.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)});
```

Use following code to emit data. When you will emit data all subscribers will get data.

```
this.dataService.data$.emit(someData);
```

Hope it will help